# Media Foundation - Sequencer Source Loop

Tags: c#, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to make a video player that plays videos in sequence, seamlessly and with looping. The "sequence" and "seamless" part was resolved by using Sequencer Source. But the "loop" part is giving me headaches!

What I'm trying to do is capture the **MEEndOfPresentation** event, and when it's captured I do these steps:

1. Pause Media Session;
2. Grab the first segment ID;
3. Call MFCreateSequencerSegmentOffset using step 2 result;
4. Call Media Session Start using step 3 result.

And this works. Works if I set **MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE** on the output node to **TRUE**. However, this produces a HUGE memory leak that reaches 2gb in minutes!

If I set **MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE** to **FALSE**, then the steps presented don't work. Is the strategy I'm using correct?

---

I logged the events to see what I'm receiving after play. Here they are in each case:

**MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE = FALSE**

```
MENewPresentation, Event Status: S_OK
# then I queue the next segment
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: StartedSource
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ended
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: SinkSwitched
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ready
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: StartedSource
MEEndOfPresentation, Event Status: S_OK, Canceled: 0
# then I do the steps mentioned
MENewPresentation, Event Status: S_OK
# then I queue the next segment
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ended
```

**MF_TOPONODE_NOSHUTDOWN_ON_REMOVE = TRUE**

```
MENewPresentation, Event Status: S_OK
# then I queue the next segment
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: StartedSource
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ended
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: SinkSwitched
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ready
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: StartedSource
MEEndOfPresentation, Event Status: S_OK, Canceled: 0
# then I do the steps mentioned
MENewPresentation, Event Status: S_OK
# then I queue the next segment
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ended
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: SinkSwitched
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ready
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: StartedSource
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: Ended
MESessionTopologyStatus, Event Status: S_OK, Topology Status: SinkSwitched
...
```

P.S. I haven't added the code because it's very large. But if you need, I can edit my question.

Comment: Since you tagged your question C#, I presume that with .NET in order to avoid the leak you might need to call some object's Dispose before the new segment, or even GC.Collect.

Comment: Yes. I have the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`'s in place and already tried GC.Collect between segments...